# Sharing a 3G USB modem over Windows ICS

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, internet, openvpn

I'm currently having issues with my ADSL connection and it's looking like it's not going to be fixed any time soon.

On my local network I have my Windows Server hardwired into my wireless router. I've had the idea of using a 3G USB dongle plugged directly into my server and then using ICS to share that with the local area connection.

Would all other computers on the network then be able to use that connection to get online?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Have your Computer wired to the internet port on your router.

**Computer > WAN port or Internet port on router.**

Have the 3G USB dongle on the computer.

Bridge the connection with your 3G USB dongle and your ethernet card.

**1.** Go to Network Connections.

**2.** Hold <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> and Select the Network Adapters you want to Bridge.

**3.** Right Click and Select Bridge connections.

This should share the internet.

Let me know if you need more details.